# Reduced functionality for opencl built-in vector types using microsoft compiler?

Tags: c, opencl, header-files

I was using a char vector type in opencl (v1.1) and was searching 
for the vector.lo and vector.hi extensions, but could only access the cl_char array s.
Searching through the opencl header files I found the following listing, 
which suggests that those extensions are available for GNUC and "strict ansi".

```
/* Define cl_vector types in cl_platform.h */
/* ---- cl_charn ---- */
typedef union
{
  cl_char  CL_ALIGNED(2) s[2];
#if defined( __GNUC__) && ! defined( __STRICT_ANSI__ )
  __extension__ struct{ cl_char  x, y; };
  __extension__ struct{ cl_char  s0, s1; };
  __extension__ struct{ cl_char  lo, hi; };
#endif
#if defined( __CL_CHAR2__) 
  __cl_char2     v2; 
#endif  
}cl_char2;

// other vector type definitions follow...
```

Is this correct? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "reduced functionality" is caused by a bug.
The details can be found at [Khronos Public Bugzilla (Bug 413)](http://www.khronos.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=413)

Some **"sloppy"** workaround is described at [Bug 413 - Workaround](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=3990).
Note this is limited to ms compiler.